# How can I store a string locally in Android?

Tags: android, string, save, local-storage

If I have a string, how can I locally save it into the user's device? I don't mind it being in a file. If it is easier using Parse.com, please show me how.
The string I want to save:

```
    final String userIDString = user.getObjectId().toString();
```

Please help me. I am using parse to get a user's object ID, so don't worry about the string. Just tell me how to save a string locally into a phone.
Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    // initialize SharedPreferences var
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        // get or create SharedPreferences 
        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myPref", MODE_PRIVATE);

        // save your string in SharedPreferences
        sharedPref.edit().putString("user_id", userIDString).commit();
    }
}
```

And for getting your String from SharedPreferences:

```
String userId = sharedPref.getString("user_id", "default if empty");
```

See more about data storage using SharedPreferences [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)